# How to change the default log_scale on the x and y axis from 1e+1 to 10^1 in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

I would like to change the default logscale axis labels from 1e-3 to 10^-3 (for example) in matplotlib

I have tried:
`ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))`, as well as the following with `ScalarFormatter`:

`plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='both',useMathText=True)`, and a number of variations, including `minor_formatter`.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))

ax.plot(dfestspec.freq, dfestspec.E_fnwn)
ax.plot(dfmodspec.freq, dfmodspec.E_fnwn, color='r')

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')

plt.ylim([0.001,1])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='both',useMathText=True)
```

unfortunately, nothing I have tried seems to change  the notation, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please ignore.. this question stemmed from displayed output in Jupyter Notebook, however, the plot is saved in the preferred format.

Comment: If by "ignore" you mean noone should read this question anymore, you can simply delete it.